# Access query does not work with CheckBox value true

Tags: ms-access

I've got a problem that's driving me nuts. I have a checkbox that when checked is supposed to update a table with it's record. The query uses the ID number and Closed = true to filter the data.

The query I'm using works fine in the query builder. And if I just add a number to the IDNum field it works fine, but when I use the IDNum form field the query fails. I've made sure I'm calling the IDNum field correctly since it's a number. Nothing I do makes it work.

Thank you for your help.
Maxine

```
Code
    Private Sub ckClosed_Click()
        Dim str_sql As String
        Dim intIDNum As Long


    intIDNum = Me.IDNum


    If Me.ckClosed.Value = -1 Then
        If DLookup("IDNum", "GCSNOTDEVTRACK_LAST", "IDNum = " & Me.IDNum) Then
            Debug.Print "Value exist in table already"
            Exit Sub
        Else
        Debug.Print "Inside Click True Else"
        str_sql = "INSERT INTO GCSNOTDEVTRACK_LAST ( IDNum, [Control Number], [Publication Number], ClosedIssue, Status, CurrentState, Combined, IssueID, Priority, Mark ) " _
            & "SELECT GCSNOTDEVTRACK.IDNum, GCSNOTDEVTRACK.ControlNo, GCSNOTDEVTRACK.[Publication No], GCSNOTDEVTRACK.ClosedIssue, GCSNOTDEVTRACK.Status, GCSNOTDEVTRACK.[Current State], GCSNOTDEVTRACK.Combined, GCSNOTDEVTRACK.[Issue ID], GCSNOTDEVTRACK.Priority, GCSNOTDEVTRACK.Match " _
            & "FROM GCSNOTDEVTRACK WHERE (((GCSNOTDEVTRACK.IDNum)=" & intIDNum & ") AND ((GCSNOTDEVTRACK.ClosedIssue)=True));"
        DoCmd.RunSQL str_sql
       End If
    'Else

        '    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the second criteria in my query and that fixed the problem